# Offset Edge wrong Width

Tags: edges

I wish to offset the edge by 5mm. I used Offset edge, but I don't understand the unit of the Width that you put in. I does not seem to be correctly working. Any advice?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your scale is not 1:1:1. [`Apply`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html) it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Scale*:

[image]